# What are questions like “why did the chicken cross the road” called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, questions, hypernyms

What are questions like

> Why did the chicken cross the road?

called? I want to know if there is a particular term given to these type of questions.

Comment: *Riddles* or *conundrums* (*conundra* if you want to be really pedantic).

Comment: yeah, I agree they are like conundrums, but then they end up being paradoxes since you have got millions of theoretical solutions to it and there is no one single/particular answer to them like we have in riddles.

So, I was just wondering if there is a particular term given to them.

Comment: Hello, @StoneyB. I'm wondering whether there is difference between riddles and crazy questions. In this case I suppose we should classify the question in the latter category.

Comment: That is a joke.

Comment: Vishal, @Carlo_R. ... as a literary form, "why did the chicken" is a riddle, and it's only funny because it **is** a riddle. The fact that its original 1847 version is known through the English-speaking world as the archetypal anti-joke, and in consequence it has spawned hundreds of parodistic answers, doesn't make it any less a riddle.

Comment: @Carlo_R. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_did_the_chicken_cross_the_road%3F) it is.

Comment: @Carlo_R- It's not the question that is supposed to be funny- It is the answer to that question that is funny.  Many answers are not funny (anymore) but there are occasionally new ones that come along, and some classics that I still smile at.  For example. "To see a man lay bricks."

Comment: @Vishal: You should edit your question, and elaborate more on what you mean by "these type of questions." As others have indicated, _Why did the chicken cross the road_ could be regarded in several legitimate ways: as a riddle, or a joke, or a silly question, or even a rhetorical question, depending on the context. Maybe you could give a couple more examples, to narrow down what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

> [Koan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/koan)

or

> [Riddle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddle)

Though this kind of question could be called a 'joke' - the humorous context of some questions can allude to a deeper philosophical proposition.... which can be funny in the context it is presented.

---

Consider the parable(s) of [the Sphinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx#The_Riddle_of_the_Sphinx), and mythological creature that tested the *dimensions of character* through riddles.

I like the etymological root of "sphinx" (*"shesepankh"*), meaning "living image", because of the poetic connection to the **life** that is ultra-present in questions like are asked-about here (jokes, riddles, etc).  I think these questions are 'more alive' and thus are more of a "living image"

Comment: I don't find this answer unreasonable. Why would anyone vote it down? Am I being unreasonably paranoid that there are people of higher plane of consciousness condescending upon our answers?

Comment: @BlessedGeek I was downvoted 'in punishment' by someone for condescending reasons.  If you like the answer then no one stops you from voting!